# multithreading splitting arrays and finding index

Tags: c++, arrays, multithreading, operating-system

This program is supposed to read from a text file and create an array with the size of the first number in the file and fill it with the other number which is going to be zeros and ones

if the value is zero it means that the bulb is defective if it's equal to 1 the bulb is working.
 This assignment is made to get familiar with using threads so the recursion of the array splitting has to work that way by the end of the code we want to know how many threads were created and trace back the zeros to find there index on the first array and display the indices.

the issue that I'm having is that I can't figure out how to trace those values up when I have two threads in my function running and doing each recursion concurrently can anyone help me out with this. 
I would like to store these values in a vector hence the print vector function being invoked later on.

Thank you.

```
// COEN346-Ass1.cpp : This file contains the 'main' function. Program execution begins and ends there.
//
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <thread>
#include <fstream>
#include <array>
#include <vector>


using namespace std;

static int TheCounter;
static vector<int> DefectiveBulbs;


void printVec(vector<int> vec) {
    if (!DefectiveBulbs.empty()) {
        cout << "Defective bulbs are : ";
        for (int i = 0; i < vec.size(); i++) {
            cout << vec.at(i) << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}

void FindDefective(int Arr[] , int size) {
    bool check = false;
    int scope = size;
    for (int i = 0; i < scope; i++) {
        if (Arr[i] == 0) {

            check = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (check == false && TheCounter == 0) {
        cout << "All bulbs are working properly" << endl;
    }
    if (scope == 1) {}

    else if (check == true) {
        int pivot = scope / 2;
        int *LeftArr = new int[scope / 2];
        int *RightArr = new int[scope / 2];
        for (int i = 0; i < pivot; i++) {
            LeftArr[i] = Arr[i];
            RightArr[i] = Arr[scope / 2 + i];
        }
        thread t1(FindDefective,LeftArr , scope/2);
        thread t2(FindDefective,RightArr,scope/2);
        t1.join();
        t2.join();
    }
    TheCounter++;
}

void BulbArr() {
    ifstream infile;
    string fileName;
    label :
    cout << "please enter file name (example: bulb.txt) :\n";
    cin >> fileName;
    infile.open(fileName);
    if (!infile.fail()) {
        int size;
        infile >> size;
        int *bulb = new int[size];
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            infile >> bulb[i];
            if (bulb[i] > 1 || bulb[i] < 0) {
                cout << "input file has wrong values please try again.";
                goto label;
            }
        }
        thread t3(FindDefective, bulb , size);
        t3.join();

    }
}
int main()
{
    BulbArr();
    printVec(DefectiveBulbs);

    cout << "The number of threads for this problem was : " << TheCounter << endl;

}
```

Comment: This starts a thread: `thread t3(FindDefective, bulb , size);` and the line after `t3.join();` waits for the thread to finish, which effectively makes it pointless to start the thread in the first place.

Comment: The blatant memory leaks notwithstanding, starting two `thread`s then waiting on both is an anti-pattern; it needlessly starts one more thread than needed. You already have a second thread (the one you're running on). Start a thread with half the workload, do the other half workload on the *current* thread, then wait for the one you started (i.e. join). Your scheduler will thank you.